# how to use group_by%>%sum in lapply?

Tags: r, group-by, sum, lapply

I have this df as an example

```
df = data.frame(x = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),
                y = 1:10,
                z = 11:20)
```

and I wish to use `lapply` with `group_by%>%sum` so I have the following output

```
  x  y  z
1 1 15 65
2 2 40 90
```

Comment: Look at [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)

Comment: In this case you can do `df %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise_all(sum)`

Comment: Why `lapply()`? You could use `aggregate()`: `aggregate(df[c('y', 'z')], df['x'], sum)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 3 ways of doing it

```r
library(dplyr)
# 1
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), \(x) sum(x, na.rm = T))

# 2 (requires the new version of dplyr)
df %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), \(x) sum(x, na.rm = T)), .by = x)

# 3 (deprecated, use with old versions of dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise_all(\(x) sum(x, na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1    15    65
2     2    40    90
```

Comment: and if I had missing values and I wish to include the argument na.rm in the function sum. How can I make that happen ?